# Does apache2 inherits .htaccess settings for nested virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have 2 virtual host:

first:

```
/home/user/website
```

second

```
/home/user/website/sub
```

Now I have a .htaccess in website that changes the default 404 Not Found pages.

How Can I set .htaccess in /home/user/website doens't affect the other virtual host too (/home/user/website/sub)?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it back to the default value in the .htaccess for /home/user/website/sub:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```